# Why Storyboard not working properly, ViewController design is not visible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, viewcontroller

I know this question is asked several time on SO but this one is still important as it may solve problems of latest versions of Xcode and Swift. Previous same questions on SO are now outdated.

I am working on an app which consists of 15 to 20 view controllers. Approximately every view controller has design which is designed in storyboard. But I am unable to see my views inside the view controllers. following is my specifications

> **What I am Using:**  I am using latest version of Xcode "Version 11.2.1 (11B500)" and my os version is Mojave "Version = 10.14.5"

But I am having ViewController like this in  storyboard.

[image: Storyboard issues]

> In this picture on left you can see some issues also and I do not know
>   how to fixed them

**What I have done: I have done following (after searching on SO) but nothing is working for me**

1. I have cleaned derived data and restarted my xcode
2. I have de-integrated my pods and re installed them
3. I have updated my xcode to latest version 11.2 and cleared derived data but still same

Please help me its been a week that I am not getting it done. Thanks

Comment: @matt this is not the same issue, please read it again

Comment: I do not know why this question is closed, however the copied question that is tagged above did not solved my problem

Comment: any one know about this issue?